# gmap-autocomplete Pick first result on Enter key in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

```
<gmap-autocomplete :value="value"
                   @place_changed="setPlace"
></gmap-autocomplete>
```

This is how i am using gmap-autocomplete component,
i want to make first location selected on enter click.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the core files,
we can simply pass select-first-on-enter prop to gmap-autocomplete to make first location select on enter.

`:select-first-on-enter=true`

Here is the updated component usage.

```
<gmap-autocomplete :value="value"
                   :select-first-on-enter="true"
                   @place_changed="setPlace"
></gmap-autocomplete>
```